# How can I make it so I click on one smaller image so it changes the larger version of the image?

Tags: css, html

For e.g. I have 4 thumbnails and 1 large image.  When I click on a thumbnail, the larger image changes to that thumbnail picture.

I thought there might be a value to place inside target=""?

I was hoping to use only html/css as I don't know other languages well but any solution would be great I've tried looking everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possible solutions:

1. Pure HTML: Use an `<iframe>` with a `name` to contain the larger image, and embed the thumbnail images in `<a>`s with the appropriate `target` and `href`
2. Pure CSS: Include all 4 pictures, with `display: none` set, and `display: block` within a rule with the `:target` pseudo class, and each with an `id`. Embed the thumbnail images in `<a>`s with `href=#id`.

Then there are of course the Javascript/jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the answer you need. There is some JavaScript but it's very basic.

[Simple Image Swap](http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/simple-image-swap.php)